# display error messages without brackets in rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

```
render( json: UserSerializer.response_error(current_user.errors.messages).to_json)
```

user_serializer.rb

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email

  def self.response_error(error)
     error
  end
end
```

It gives the response as below:

```
[
"Password can't be blank"
]
```

But I need to display

```
"Password can't be blank"
```

I tried to use "full_messages" but the result was same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def self.response_error(error)
  error.join(', ')
end
```

You could do it like this. The issue is it needs to be an array. Since there could be multiple errors like.

```
[
  "Email can't be blank",
  "Password can't be blank"
]
```

This will be result with the above code in:

```
"Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank"
```

In general an array is easier to work with in the frontend regardless of one or many errors.

When you are absolutely sure there will only this one error you could also do
`error.join('')` to just get the string.

Comment: Thank you, it's worked for me. Upvoted and Accepted your answer.